# IE doesn't fire change event on select on enter and tab

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

I have a code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#my_select").change(function(e){alert(e);})
            $("#my_select").focus();
        });
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="my_select">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <input />
  </body>
  </html>
```

open in IE, select will be in focus, select any number with up/down/letters keyboard buttons, and press enter/tab key no alert will be fired. WHY????

PS: yes jquery version is old, I know about it, but I can't switch to newer one now.
PS2: IE8 and IE6

Comment: your code is working fine with my IE version 9. which IE version you have?

Comment: Does the `change` events fires when pressing up/down? It should do so, not on enter though.

Comment: This seems to be just internet explorer, it works in the newest version of google chrome anyway :), for anyone attempting to solve the question here is a jsfiddle to help you out: http://jsfiddle.net/nzgQ2/1/

Comment: Change events fires while pressing up/down keyboard buttons. I dont need to press enter/tab.  @MaxArt you should try this code.

Comment: I can't use jQuery 1.7.2, my project uses 1.4.2, in ie8 event fires on enter or tab, not on each up/down

Comment: I tried it with chrome. In that, I need to press enter key for alert call.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh dear, sorry, I didn't notice Alpesh' reputation. Maybe I'm doing more damage by down-voting... Removing the vote.

Comment: pls look at header, it is IE (internet explorer) problem not google chrome, not firefox, not opera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably won't fire on blur (enter/tab) as it would've already fired on the arrow up or down -- which it does just that when trying it in IE9.

IE (also Opera) has been consistent in being "buggy" with handling the `change` event for `<select>` elements: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html#t05

Also note that issues between jQuery 1.4.2 and older versions of IE may be contributing to this, as a few bugs were reported for 1.4.2 and fixed in 1.4.3: [#6374](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6374) and [#6956](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6956).

Comment: thank you very much for these links, do you have any ideas how to fix it without changing jQuery version?